# How to build a maven web application where the .java files are in WEB-INF/classes

Tags: java, maven

I recently imported a Maven web app from Git.It has the following structure.

```
root directory
-images
-css
META-INF
    - embedded maven project with pom.xml
    - MANIFEST.MF
WebContent
    - META-INF
        - MANIFEST.MF
    WEB-INF
        -lib
        -web.xml
WEB-INF
    -classes
        - abc.java
        - xyz.java
```

I want to add changes in abc.java and build it. But in run as option, I don't see Maven build option. Please let me know how to build such a Maven project.

Comment: Java source code belongs to `src/main/java` `WEB-INF/classes` is the target Please see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: I know, but the project I imported has the above structure. is there a possible way to build it, or is there a way to rearrange it and then build it?

Comment: The way to rearrange is to move the files to the appropriate locations...

Comment: I rearranged the files and I could build it successfully. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

To declare the directory `WEB-INF\classes` as your source directory you have to set the `sourceDirectory` maven property by

```
<build>
   <sourceDirectory>WEB-INF/classes</sourceDirectory>
   ...
</build>
```

then Maven get the .java files from that directory.

Comment: First using a back slash is simply wrong furthermore the class directory is no source directory...

Comment: you named your files *.java in WEB-INF\classes as those are source files. Class directory should contains *.class files

Comment: and maven can deal with \ and /

Comment: You should use forward slash instead of the backslash because Java handles that..